# Discord Bot DM all but only one person per 5 secs

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey is it possible to code a Dm all command what only DM 1 person per 5 second? ( Node.js / Discord.js)

Answer (score 0):

I think that would fall under API Abuse according to Discord's ToS due to the use of it for spamming.

If this is allowed, however, is it in a specific server or is it a group of people that don't neccesarily share the same server?

Comment: Hello i just want that the Bot DMs Everyone where the Bot is inside